# Where to put API Calls in Redux that change props but not state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, architecture, react-redux, flux

I am calling an API endpoint to populate a table with a large number of rows. Users can click on a row and are then being re-directed to a page on which they can edit the element. They can never edit anything in the table itself. They are always being redirected to a separate page.

I was thinking quite a bit about this and believe that this *is not state*. It cannot change. Right?

**Question:** Where, in a Redux application, do I fetch the data from my API and pass in the result as props into the table? Would I still do this inside a `Redux action`? This seems wrong, since my action won't modify state at all: the data I get back will just but statically displayed. **But:** if not in a `Redux action`, where else? In the component itself? I'm not sure about this either, because it seems neat to have all actions of an application in the actions folder/files.

What would you recommend?

**PS:** One could also argue that the elements in the table *are state*, since they are being modified -only on separate pages (never in the table itself). But the data I would have to fetch for this would be quite big, and users would only engage with one element of that table at a time, so it seems that would simply be misusing Redux as a database. It seems to make more sense to have the currently clicked on item as state, and fetch a light-weight list from server, which just populates the table, but does not hold any of the other nested data (that I can always grab whenever the users selects which item he/she wants to edit) Does that seem right?

Answer (score 0):

You can mix your app's state with Redux and React's local state. This is not wrong. It depends how you set up you app's logic. For your situation, for example, if those fetched data won't be needed anywhere else apart from this component you can hold this data in your component's state.

Your component will fetch the data, hold the state then pass the relevant props to a child component (where the data will be edited) and you will do the rest there. Also no other components will need those data. If this is the situation holding the state in your component seems logical to me (as a learner).

Comment: So you suggest I simply fetch it in the component? I don't see why you say that the component should hold the data as state though, on my understanding, since I am not modifying the the data, the data shouldn't go into state but only ever be props. What do you think?

Comment: Where do you see that "if the data won't change then it should not go to into state"? You can hold anything in your state, whether it is being changed or not. If you don't fetch your data in this component, rather prefer get this as a prop, then where do you plan to fetch this data? In a parent component for sure, then without using any state how do you plan to pass this data as prop? I might read your question somehow wrong. I understood that whether you want to use Redux or React's state as a mix. This is how I answered.

Comment: Yeah this is not what I'm asking. I understand that strictly speaking I can put into state whatever I want, but the way I understood state was that you should generally adhere to the principle that state should only hold what might change during the running of the app. (Let me know if thats wrong, I'm only a beginner). But: what you are saying is basically, that at some point or other the data should be in state, and only then passed as a prop to sub-components? I would have just fetched it and passed it down straightaway, without saving it in the parents-component state first.

Comment: I did not see any advise like yours up to now. Whether there will be a change or not, I use state to hold my components data. Then, it would be better to add some boilerplate code from your app. Hence, people can see if there might be some problems using your method or no problem at all. I mean without using state directly fetching and passing the data as props.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your API endpoint in redux action and than pass the response in payload to the reducer that will put data returned from your APi to the state.

Comment: That would be the standard Redux flow, wouldn't it? My question is precisely what to do if I do not want to put my API data into state.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to access the result data from the state:

1. call api with redux action
2. get the data (and filter if you want) in the reducer
3. put the result data in the main redux store
4. use the result data directly with `this.props.<result_data_name>` in the react component.

If you want to pass these data to child component, still use the props only, as the table is read-only, you don't need to store anything in the react state.

In this way, you don't need to put props data into state to use it. just directly use the data from props itself.